# How to make a LIKE query in where safe against SQLi

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-injection, where-clause, rails-activerecord

I have this line

```
 User.where("email LIKE ?", "%#{@search}%")
```

which brakeman says it could be used for sql injection

Is there a better, safer way to write this line (to search for users with email having `@search` in it)

Comment: It does not look like a line with parameterized SQL could be used for SQL injection.

Comment: If that line is indeed a parametrized query in instead of simple string substitution then it is safe.

Comment: even in a LIKE query?

Comment: even in a like query.  However, it could be used for a cross site scripting attack, but that's not your question.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: Sadly it is both, sort of. Rails deals with placeholders itself in most cases so it is a pseudo-parameterized query and the database will see an SQL string with the placeholders filled in (and presumably properly escaped) by Rails.

Comment: Is this the actual code? Brakeman should not warn on this and I cannot reproduce the warning. If you could provide the full warning that would be very helpful. [Filing an issue](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/issues) would be even more helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It couldn't be used for injection.
This way is already safe.